# StatefulSet not created pod after deleting running pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

Guys I have very strage issue my StatefulSet pod not created after I delete successfully runned pod

**kubectl get sts -n jenkins**

```
NAME      READY   AGE
jenkins   1/1     142d
```

but no pods creting
Help Please any idea???

**kubectl describe sts jenkins -n jenkins**

```
Name:               jenkins
Namespace:          jenkins
CreationTimestamp:  Fri, 30 Jun 2023 16:18:01 +0600
Selector:           app=jenkins
Labels:             app=jenkins
                    section=tools
Annotations:        <none>
Replicas:           1 desired | 2 total
Update Strategy:    RollingUpdate
  Partition:        0
Pods Status:        0 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:           app=jenkins
                    section=tools
  Service Account:  jenkins-account
  Containers:
   jenkins:
    Image:       docker-c2.xyz.com/jenkins/jenkins:v0.1
    Ports:       8080/TCP, 50000/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Limits:
      cpu:     2
      memory:  2Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:     50m
      memory:  256Mi
    Environment:
      JAVA_OPTS:                 -Xms2g -Xmx2g
      JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT:  50000
    Mounts:
      /var/jenkins_home from jenkins-home (rw)
  Volumes:  <none>
Volume Claims:
  Name:          jenkins-home
  StorageClass:  jenkins-storage
  Labels:        <none>
  Annotations:   <none>
  Capacity:      80Gi
  Access Modes:  [ReadWriteOnce]
Events:          <none>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

I suppose issue come from `kube-scheduler` yesterday I renewed certs on Master node. After renewing I did only `systemctl restart kubelet`  not restarted `kube-scheduler`.

### Solution

I rebooted master node then issue gone. `Pods` re-created

Everything working